# Allowing HTML text in asp textbox w/o using validateRequest=false

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to send a html  text entered in  asp.net text box without making validaterequest to false.

Thanks,
Amit Shah

Comment: Have you tried using Server.HTMLEncode() on the contents of the textbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably add some javascript to encode the textbox value before the form is submitted.

something like:

```
$(function() {
  $("form").submit(function() {
    var myTextBox = $("#myTextBox");
    myTextBox.val( encodeMyHtml( myTextBox.val() ) );
  });
});

function encodeMyHtml(encodedHtml) {
  encodedHtml = escape(encodedHtml);
  encodedHtml = encodedHtml.replace(/\//g,"%2F");
  encodedHtml = encodedHtml.replace(/\?/g,"%3F");
  encodedHtml = encodedHtml.replace(/=/g,"%3D");
  encodedHtml = encodedHtml.replace(/&/g,"%26");
  encodedHtml = encodedHtml.replace(/@/g,"%40");
  encodeHtml.htmlEncoded.value = encodedHtml;
}
```

Comment: I should add that the user will probably see the value of the textbox change into the encoded value while the form is submitting.

Answer (score 0):

[Control.ValidateRequestMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.validaterequestmode.aspx), new to .NET 4.5, might be of interest to you. It allows you to specify how individual controls are validated.